# ¿Cómo ignorar símbolos reservados en expresiones regulares?

Tags: python, regex

Quiero contar la cantidad de veces que un símbolo '+' es seguido por un dígito del 0 al 7. Por ejemplo, en la cadena '+3+9+2' esto ocurre en '+3' y '+2', o sea que sería un total de 2 ocasiones.

Intenté lo siguiente:

```
contar_plus_sigue_octal = lambda op: len (re.findall("+[0-7]", op))
```

Pero me aparece un error porque aparentemente el '+' significa otra cosa. ¿Existe la posibilidad de tratar al '+' como un símbolo común?

Comment: El signo `+` significa 1 o más apariciones de lo que le antecede, por eso hay que escaparlo con \ , o sea: "\+[0-7]"

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
import re

intro = "+3+9+2"
#creamos la expresion regular
# agrupando todas las coincidencias
regex =r"(\+[1-7])+"

# compilamos
r = re.compile(regex)
# buscamos y luego medimos su longitud
len(r.findall(intro))
```

Comment: Yo completaria mas tu respuesta explicando como se escapa ciertos caracteres en una expresion regular. Pero por lo demas todo bien c:

Answer (score -2):

**Long story short**: usa un IDE y GitHub copilot

No sé qué tan válida sea esta respuesta, pero acabo de descubrir Github Copilot, y para que este servicio resuelva esta pregunta, tan sólo hay que saber describir la función:

```
def count_times_plus_followed_by_number_in_range(text: str) -> int:
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual me lleva a preguntarme sobre el futuro de SO gracias a Github Copilot y las IDE's.

Comment: Habrá más gente que crea estar aprendiendo a programar.

Comment: -1, no me encuentro a favor de que una ide le proponga al programador ideas que deberian ocurrirseles a ellos. La gente se volvera dependiente y dejara de pensar por si misma. Sobre la ultima oracion, SO seguirá, un ide automatizado no puede resolver todos los errores. Por ultimo, yo diria que describas en que parte de la regex un caracter es escapado.

Comment: Ese ide, no deberia de existir, es hasta preocupante la existencia de esto.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con todos ustedes y el -1.  Lo hice como experimento porque creo que una temática bien descrita se puede "contestar" a si misma, entonces, si el requerimiento del OP está bien explicado, su pregunta se podría "contestar" "a si misma" con Github Copilot.

Comment: Además, Github Copilot, hasta donde lo he usado, no contesta así por que si; sino que tienes que usar las "buenas prácticas" como naming adecuado y documentación. Pero eso será tema de otra conversación.